# What's the size limit of Cache Storage for Service Worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

The size of Local Storage is limit to 5M, and is there any limit of Cache Storage when I used in Service Worker?

Answer (score 6):

As of Aug 15 2016, Addy Osmani [posted](https://medium.com/dev-channel/offline-storage-for-progressive-web-apps-70d52695513c#.mj8pndkae):

> How much can you store? In Chrome and Opera: Your storage is per
>   origin (rather than per API). Both storage mechanisms will store data
>   until the browser [quota](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/) is reached. Apps can check how much quota
>   they’re using with the Quota Management API. Firefox: no limits, but
>   will prompt after 50MB data stored. Mobile Safari: 50MB max, Desktop
>   Safari: unlimited (prompts after 5MB), IE10+ maxes at 250MB and
>   prompts at 10MB. PouchDB [track](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html#data_limits) IDB storage behavior. Future facing:
>   For apps requiring more persistent storage, see the on-going work on
>   [Durable Storage](https://storage.spec.whatwg.org/).

Where *per origin* means that API's like localStorage would be sharing storage space with API's like the service worker Cache.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer** is that it will be browser specific and as of now (August 30, 2016) most browsers haven't started support.

**The long answer** is that the Cache, provided for in the Service Workers spec is still a working draft. Check out w3 org service-worker spec for more info if interested:
https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/

The following, per Mozilla's documentation, lists browser compatibility with service workers as well as Cache API.

**Web/API/Caches**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache#Browser_compatibility

**Service Worker API**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker#Browser_compatibility

As more browsers support these APIs, it will be easier to chart browser implementation to cache limitation to correctly address your question. I encourage others to improve this answer as developments occur.

For the time being Jake Archibald -- an editor of the service worker spec -- has provided the following site to help monitor and inform developers of readiness of service workers, including caches in various browsers:

[Is Service Worker Ready?](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the end browser. Chrome allows you to ask for unlimited storage (limited by the users hard drive size online), by default it is 5 MB. Safari and Firefox both default to unlimited cache. Mobile devices are again different Chrome (Android) in the mobile defaults to unlimited while safari (iOS) limits to 10MB.

[Source](http://grinninggecko.com/2011/02/24/developing-cross-platform-html5-offline-app-1/)

Comment: It seems, according to your source, that you confuse with appcache which is being [deprecated](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#offline).